# SparkR reading and writing dataframe issue

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a Spark DataFrame which I want to write to my disc, I used the following code-

```
write.df(data_frame,"dataframe_temp.csv",source="csv",mode="overwrite",schema="true",header="true")
```

It got completed and I can see a new folder created with a `_SUCCESS` file in it.

Now when I am trying to read from the same file, using following code-

```
dataframe2<-read.df("dataframe_temp.csv",inferSchema="true",header="true")
```

I am getting following error:

> ERROR RBackendHandler: loadDF on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils
>   failed Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName,
>   ...) :    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer
>   schema for ParquetFormat at dataframe.csv. It must be specified
>   manually;

I have even tried using repartition

```
data_frame<-repartition(data_frame,1)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to specify the source as "csv":

```
dataframe2<-read.df("dataframe_temp.csv", source="csv")
```

Regarding the **header** argument:

Currently there is also a bug in SparkR for Spark 2.0, where the variable arguments of the `write.df` function aren't passed to the options parameter (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17442). That's why the header is not written to the csv even if you specify `header="true"` on `write.df`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved using parquet file format, parquet file format stores the schema by default.

Comment: could you elaborate, it's not clear how you went from finding the parquet schema to using `parquetFile` successfuly